# How to track rectangle with specific color

Tags: python, c++, image, opencv, python-imaging-library

I only found samples for face tracking.

How can i track the rectangles with specific color?

And I need its pixels.

[image]

Comment: You basically iterate over your screen and look for the specific color value. Once you found it you have to iterate over a section that is barely the size of the square from that position on and check if all the values match. Let me tell you that this is the worst way of writing bots for video games, it's super error prone and takes a ton of computing power if you want to update every single frame, even if you find a way of optimizing it. A way better approach would be to get these coordinates directly from the Ram or from your socket stream, this won't be possible in Python though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a script that will do it:

```
from PIL import Image
from math import sqrt

RED = 0
GREEN = 1
BLUE = 2
COLORS = [RED, GREEN, BLUE]
RED_HEALTH = (234, 105, 112)
BLUE_HEALTH = (84, 165, 226)
HEALTH_BORDER = (0, 0, 0)
image = Image.open("image.jpg")

def close_enough_to(src, target, delta):
    diff = 0
    for color in COLORS:
        diff += (src[color] - target[color]) ** 2
    diff = sqrt(diff)
    return diff <= delta

class HealthBar:
    def __init__(self, team, health_percentage, length, pos):
        self.team = team
        self.health_percentage = health_percentage
        self.length = length
        self.pos = pos

    def __str__(self):
        return "team {}, percentage {}, length {}, pos {}".format(self.team,
                self.health_percentage,
                self.length,
                self.pos
                )

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

def flood_fill_health_bar(image, pos, color, traversed):
    (x, y) = pos
    health_pixels = 0
    while close_enough_to(image.getpixel((x, y)), color) \
        and (x, y) not in traversed:
        health_pixels += 1
        traversed.add((x, y))
        x += 1
    black_pixels = 0
    while close_enough_to(image.getpixel((x, y)), HEALTH_BORDER, 50) \
        and (x, y) not in traversed:
        black_pixels += 1
        traversed.add((x, y))
        x += 1
    if black_pixels > 0:
        if color is RED_HEALTH:
            team = "red" 
        else:
            team = "blue"
        percent_health = health_pixels / (health_pixels + black_pixels)
        return HealthBar(team, percent_health, health_pixels + black_pixels, pos)

def in_bounds(image, pos):
    return pos[0] >= 0 and pos[1] >= 0 \
            and pos[0] < image.width and pos[1] < image.height

def flood_fill_image(image, start, delta):
    flood_fill_queue = [start]
    traversed = []
    color = image.getpixel(start)
    pos = start
    pix = image.load()
    while len(flood_fill_queue):
        (x, y) = flood_fill_queue.pop()
        positions = [(x+1, y), (x-1, y), (x, y+1), (x, y-1)]
        for position in positions:
            if in_bounds(image, position) \
                    and close_enough_to(image.getpixel(position), color, delta):
                if position not in traversed:
                    flood_fill_queue.append(position)
                    traversed.append(position)
                    (x, y) = position
                    pix[x, y] = (0, 0, 255)
    return traversed

def get_width(positions):
    return get_max_x(positions) - get_min_x(positions)

def get_height(positions):
    return get_max_y(positions) - get_min_y(positions)

def get_max_x(positions):
    return sorted(list(positions), key=lambda x: x[0])[-1][0]

def get_max_y(positions):
    return sorted(list(positions), key=lambda x: x[1])[-1][1]

def get_min_x(positions):
    return sorted(list(positions), key=lambda x: x[0])[0][0]

def get_min_y(positions):
    return sorted(list(positions), key=lambda x: x[1])[0][1]

def find_health_bars(image):
    traversed = set()
    health_bars = []
    pix = image.load()
    (width, height) = image.size
    for col in range(0, width):
        for row in range(0, height):
            #  pix = image.getpixel((col, row))
            if (col, row) in traversed:
                continue 
            for health_color in [RED_HEALTH, BLUE_HEALTH]:
                border_pixels = []
                if close_enough_to(image.getpixel((col, row)), health_color, 10):
                    health_pixels = flood_fill_image(image, (col, row), 100)
                    for pos in health_pixels:
                        (x, y) = pos
                        traversed.add(pos)
                        pix[x, y] = (255, 255, 0)
                    border_pixels = flood_fill_image(image, (col - 1, row - 1), 30)
                    if len(border_pixels) is 0:
                        continue
                    health_bar_width = get_width(border_pixels)
                    health_bar_height = get_height(border_pixels)
                    health_width = get_width(health_pixels)
                    if abs(health_bar_width / health_bar_height) - 10 <= 0.5:
                        team = "blue" if health_color == BLUE_HEALTH else "red"
                        percent_health = health_width / health_bar_width
                        health_bar = HealthBar(team, percent_health, health_bar_width, (col, row))
                        health_bars.append(health_bar)

                for pos in border_pixels:
                    (x, y) = pos
                    traversed.add(pos)
                    pix[x, y] = (0, 255, 255)
    health_bars = [health_bar for health_bar in health_bars if health_bar is not None]
    health_bars.sort(key=lambda x: x.length)
    return health_bars

health_bars = find_health_bars(image)

print(health_bars)
```

Basically this is the algorithm:

1. Traverse the entire image, looking for the red / blue of a health bar
2. Once we find that, run a super hacky flood-fill function to find the coordinates that health bar takes up.
3. Run the same flood-fill function to get the borders of the health bar.
4. Find the width of the borders and the width of the health, and then just divide one by the other to get percent health.

Here's what it looks like visually after the flood-fills have been computed (the function doesn't play nice with your circles, I imagine that won't be a problem though...): 
[image]

Yellow areas are the health part of the health bar, and cyan is the border. As you can see it's not perfect but hopefully it's close enough. Also, I assume the images you'll use this with will be png instead of jpg, so that will eliminate a good bit of inaccuracy.

EDIT: Here's the output of printing `health_bars`:

`[team blue, percentage 1.0, length 20, pos (66, 433), team blue, percentage 1.0, length 34, pos (130, 436), team red, percentage 0.38095238095238093, length 63, pos (149, 357), team blue, percentage 0.953125, length 64, pos (27, 404), team red, percentage 0.6703296703296703, length 91, pos (480, 119), team red, percentage 0.5700934579439252, length 107, pos (500, 52)]`

Comment: really thanks, Marcus. the RED_HEALTH = (234, 105, 112), as a argument of close_enough_to, how do you get the health value?

Comment: You mean how did I come up with `(234, 105, 112)`? I just used a color picker to get the RGB values of a pixel in the health bar. If you mean how to get the health value of a minion, you want to look at the `percentage` field in the output.

Comment: Well, I just mean (234, 105, 112), i got it

Answer (score 0):

Make a list where you put in every minion, then iterate through this list and look if its either red or blue. If thats possible...